# CVXPY: possible bug in sum_squares when handling nested sums?

Tags: python, cvxpy

As part of a larger project, I end up with convex expressions like `((x_0 + x_1)^2 + x_2^2`:

```
from cvxpy import Variable, sum_squares, sum

target = Variable(3, nonneg=True, name='Target')
sum(target)
sum_squares(target)

combo = [sum([target[0], target[1]]), target[2]]
sum(combo)
sum_squares(combo)
```

`sum(combo)` works fine, but `sum_squares(combo)` throws the following error

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

despite both atoms being scalar functions of with array inputs. Is there a better way to rewrite this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum_squares` does not take array input. The input needs to be a single CVXPY `Expression`. Use `vstack`, `hstack`, or `bmat` to combine multiple `Expressions` into a single vector or matrix `Expression`.

Comment: vstack([sum([target[0], target[1]]), target[2]]) worked.  Thanks.